# Gigya socialize.removeConnection cannot remove last connected account

Tags: gigya

As in [documentation](http://developers.gigya.com/037_API_reference/010_Socialize/socialize.removeConnection) in removeConnection i found two flags i need:

> **removeLoginID:** if the social identity being removed is the last social identity and the associated login ID is the last login ID. In this case the operation fails without removing anything.
>
> **lastIdentityHandling:** Determines how to handle attempts to remove the last login identity. May be either **"soft"** or **"fail"**:
>   **"soft"** - Indicates that Gigya will remove all the stored information related to the connection, except for the mapping between this user account and the social user. This way Gigya deletes all the information about the user but the account remains accessible if the user ever tries to login again using the same social identity.

Using this two flags I am trying to remove connections for exists account.

> lastIdentityHandling:soft
>
> removeLoginID:true

When i trying to remove first one - everything ok, when last - it returns

> {"errorMessage": "Not supported",
>     "errorDetails": "Last identity cannot be removed",
>     ...
>   }

Do you have any ideas where to go?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the request didn't fulfill the conditions described in the [documentation](http://developers.gigya.com/037_API_reference/010_Socialize/socialize.removeConnection):

> **removeLoginID** Boolean Indicates whether the server should remove the login ID that is associated with the removed social network identity. **This can be done as long as the following conditions are met**:
>   1. The login ID is not associated with any other identity (site or social). 
>   2. After removing the login ID there is still another way to login to the account, i.e. either there is another social identity connected to the account or there is another login ID and password pair.
>   If these conditions are not met, for example, if the social identity being removed is the last social identity and the associated login ID is the last login ID. In this case the operation fails without removing anything.
>   The default value is "false".

I'd like to suggest contacting Gigya support for further details.